# Calculating the intersection area between two rectangles with axes not aligned

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I want to calculate the intersection over union *IoU* between two rectangles with axes not aligned, but with an angle of the axes smaller than 30 degrees. An approximate value is also seeked.

One possible solution is to check if the angle between the two rectangles is less than 30 degree and than rotate them parallel to aligne the axis. From here it is easy to calculate the *IoU*.

Another possibility is to use monte carlo methods for the intersection ( generate a point, find if the point is under some line of one rectangle and above some line of the other), but this seems expensive because I need to use this calculation a large number of times.

I was hopping that there is something better out there; maybe a geometry library, or maybe an algorithm from the computer vision folks.

I am trying to learn grasping positions using deep neural networks. My algorithem should predict a bounding box (rectangle) for an object in an rgb image. For any image I have also the ground truth (another rectangle) bounding box. From this two rectangles I need the *IoU*.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working in Python, I think the [Shapely](https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) package would serve your needs.

Comment: Indeed. But, unexpectedly it was 3 times slower from what I gathered from internet. Besides, for one polygon it showed a result twice as big as what I found. I don't know why. For rectangles they both calulate the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite effective algorithm for calculation of intersection between two convex polygons, described in O'Rourke book "Computational Geometry in C".

C code is available [at the book page](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/ftp.html) (convconv).

Algorithm traverse edges of the first polygon, checking orientations of the second polygon vertices in order to detect intersections.  When two consequent vertices lie on the different sides of the edge, intersection occurs (there is a lot of trick cases).  Algorithm outline is [here](http://www.cs.uml.edu/~kdaniels/courses/ALG_504_F12/ORourkeCH7.pdf)

Comment: Thx, but this is rather overkill for my task and also understanding the C code and writing in python can take its toll. I have always just two rectangles. If you can think also of any approximation (under the conditions mentioned in the question) will be much appreciated.

Comment: You have not mentioned - whether both rectangle have similar orientation (rotation angle).Why did you emphasize  on 30 degrees - what is special in this angle? And I cannot imagine that any estimation method is simpler than exact solution in this case.

Comment: The rectangles do not have the same orientation. If the predicted rectangle have an orientation greater than 30 degrees with the ground truth rectangle (the labeled data image) this will not be accepted. If the orientation is less than 30 degree the griper of the robot can still catch the object. So, the rectangles in fact are grasp positions. One approximation that I thought of is this: **1.** check if the orientation of the rectangles is less than 30 degrees **2** rotate both of them around the axis of their respective center til image oriented **3** easy calculate the _IoU_.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a number of numerical approaches, practically "rendering" the rectangles into some "canvas"/canvases, and traverse the pixels for making your statistics. The size of the canvas should be the size of the bounding box for the entire scene, practically you can find that via picking the minimum and maximum coordinates occurring for each axis.

1) "most CG" approach: really get a rendering library, render one rectangle with red, other rectangle with transparent blue. Then visit each pixel and if it has a non-0 red component, it belongs to the first rectangle, if it has a non-0 blue component, it belongs to the second rectangle. And if it has both, it belongs to the intersection too. This approach is cheap for coding, but requires both writing and reading the canvas even in the rendering phase, which is slower than just writing. This might be even done on GPU too, though I am not sure if setup costs and getting back the result do not weight out the benefit for such a simple scene.

2) another CG-approach would be rendering into 2 arrays, preferably some 1-byte-per-pixel variant, for the sake of speed (you may have to go back in time a bit in order to find such dedicated rendering libraries). This way the renderer only writes, into one array per rectangle, and you read from two when creating the statistics

3) as writing and reading pixels take time, you can do some shortcut, but it needs more coding: convex shapes can be rendered via collecting the minimum and maximum coordinates per scanline, and just filling between the two. If you do it yourself, you can spare the filling part and also the read-and-check-every-pixel step at the end. Build such min-max list for both rectangles, and then you "just" have to check their relation/order for each scanline, to recognize overlaps

And then there is the mathematical way: **this is not really useful, see EDIT below** while it is unlikely that you would find some sane algorithm for calculating intersection area, specifically for the case of rectangles, if you find such algorithm for triangles, which is more probable, that would be enough. Both rectangles can be split into two triangles, 1A+1B and 2A+2B respectively, and then you just have to run such algorithm 4 times: 1A-2A, 1A-2B, 1B-2A, 1B-2B, sum the results and that is the area of your intersection.

EDIT: for the maths approach (though this also comes from graphics), I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutherland%E2%80%93Hodgman_algorithm can be applied here (as both rectangles are convex polygons, A-B and B-A should produce the same result) for finding the intersection polygon, and then the remaining task is to calculate the area of that polygon (here and now I think it is going to be convex, and then it is really easy).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I will check it. But in the meanwhile, what does CG stands for?

Comment: @prometeu That part is easy: CG = Computer Graphics :-)

Comment: I will give some thoughts to the Sutherland-Hodgson algorithm. Can you tell me your opinion about my approximation that I commented in MBo's answer? Thx.

Comment: @prometeu I think the idea would work well for cases where the rectangles are square-ish and the approximation is good enough already. However if we think about "long" rectangles, rotation may have large impact, especially when the center of rotation is outside of the other rectangle.

Comment: Thx again. They are almost-square-ish. But I finished it and wrote also an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Sutherland-Hodgman algorithm implemented as this functions:

```
def clip(subjectPolygon, clipPolygon):
   def inside(p):
      return(cp2[0]-cp1[0])*(p[1]-cp1[1]) > (cp2[1]-cp1[1])*(p[0]-cp1[0])

   def computeIntersection():
      dc = [ cp1[0] - cp2[0], cp1[1] - cp2[1] ]
      dp = [ s[0] - e[0], s[1] - e[1] ]
      n1 = cp1[0] * cp2[1] - cp1[1] * cp2[0]
      n2 = s[0] * e[1] - s[1] * e[0] 
      n3 = 1.0 / (dc[0] * dp[1] - dc[1] * dp[0])
      return [(n1*dp[0] - n2*dc[0]) * n3, (n1*dp[1] - n2*dc[1]) * n3]

   outputList = subjectPolygon
   cp1 = clipPolygon[-1]

   for clipVertex in clipPolygon:
      cp2 = clipVertex
      inputList = outputList
      outputList = []
      s = inputList[-1]

      for subjectVertex in inputList:
         e = subjectVertex
         if inside(e):
            if not inside(s):
               outputList.append(computeIntersection())
            outputList.append(e)
         elif inside(s):
            outputList.append(computeIntersection())
         s = e
      cp1 = cp2
   return(outputList)

def PolygonArea(corners):
    n = len(corners) # of corners
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area

intersection = clip(rec1, rec2)
intersection_area = PolygonArea(intersection)
iou = intersection_area/(PolygonArea(rec1)+PolygonArea(rec2)-intersection_area)
```

Another slower method (don't know what algorithm) could be:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = Polygon(rec1)
p2 = Polygon(rec2)
inter_sec_area = p1.intersection(rec2).area
iou = inter_sec_area/(p1.area + p2.area - inter_sec_area)
```

It is worth mentioning that in just one case with bigger polygons (not my case) the `shapely` module had an area twice greater than the first method. I didn't test both methods intensively.

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMIun.png)

What about using Pythagorean theorem ? Since you have two rectangles, when they intersect, you will have one or more triangles, each with one angle of 90°.

Since you also know the angle between the two rectangles (20° in my example), and the coordinates of each rectangle, you can use the the appropriate function (cos/sin/tan) to know the length of all the edges of the triangles.

I hope this can help